# How can I access all field elements of a structure array nested in a cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, struct, cell-array

Here's code that creates an example cell array for this question:

```
mycell = cell([5,1]);
for i = 1 : size(mycell)
    mystruct = struct();
    mycell{i} = mystruct;
    mycell{i}.field1 = i;
end
```

I expected `mycell{:}.field1` to do what I want, but it gives an error.  I can use the following for loop:

```
for i = 1 : size(mycell)
    mycell{i}.field1
end
```

but I'd prefer a simpler or more elegant solution as a want to use all the elements of mycell.field1 as the y-variables in a plot.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Two possible solutions:

#### First:

If all the structs in your cell array have the same fields than you can:

```
mycell = [ mycell{:} ]; % convert cell array to struct array
y = [ mycell(:).filed1 ]; % get the values
```

#### Second:

Another method uses `cellfun`

```
y = cellfun( @(x) x.field1, mycell );
```

assuming all `mycell{ii}.filed1` are scalars, otherwise you'll need to add `'UniformOutput', false` to the `cellfun`.

**note:** in case some fields are empty (`[]`) these methods might not work as expected.

One small remark:
[it is not a good practice to use `i` and `j` as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: Thanks for the note about i and j.  I have definitely found debugging to be easier now that I'm not using them as for loop counters.

Comment: Unfortunately, the structs do not have all the same fields.  The cellfun method worked beautifully!  Thanks.